# Categorical features of Hilbert spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ct.category-theory, noncommutative-geometry

Does the category of Hilbert spaces and bounded maps have any particular categorical feature which can be studied systematically?

I mean, I know that it's a $*$-category, but it seems to have much more structure as an additive category: kernels, cokernels, sums, etc. However, it is not abelian nor exact.

Comment: It might be quasi-abelian in the sense of Schneiders (I forget if this is the accepted common terminology) but I don't know if that's the kind of thing you're looking for

Comment: Martti Karvonen gave a talk on [limits in dagger-categories](https://www.math.muni.cz/~loregianf/PSSL103/slides/Karvonen.pdf) at the PSSL 103. Maybe this is a good starting point?

Comment: Actually, I'm wondering about the kind of $*$-categories to which one can extend the machinery of homological algebra. For instance, the category of Hilbert modules over a $C^*$-algebra seems to be one of those categories. Maybe, the question could be rephrased as:

Q. If abelian categories are the natural abstract framework to deal with categories of modules over a ring, what should be the abstract framework to deal with categories of Hilbert modules over a $C^*$-algebra?

Of course, these categories must be $*$-categories in the first place, but this is not enought, I guess.

Comment: @EnriqueBecerra If you are wanting to do homological algebra for categories like Ban or Hilb then the existence of morphisms that are mono and epi yet not iso will force life to be more complicated. It sounds like the following paper of M. Farber https://arxiv.org/abs/dg-ga/9606013 might have something like what you are looking for? (This should somehow be a special case of the Schneiders article http://www.numdam.org/item?id=MSMF_1999_2_76__R3_0 but I never actually checked this carefully)

Comment: @YemonChoi Those references look very nice, indeed. Thanks.